# how to group 10 people in 4-4-2 group 10 times with some restrictions

Tags: combinations

The problem:

10 people decided to play a tournament of a game, which is played by four and requires a judge. The tournament consists of ten rounds. In each round 2 people are judges, four people play a game as first group, remaining four play as second group. Each person must be a judge exactly two times and they must never have the same pair (e.g. if person number 1 and person number 2 judge a round, they must not judge another round together). Each person must play exactly 8 rounds so that he meets maximum number of different opponents (i.e. Each player meets 6 out of 9 opponents 3 times and remaining 3 players two times).

What I tried:

I thought this problem was similar to 8 queens problem, so I wrote a recursive function, but then I realised, that 8 queens problem needs to check 8^8 (8 in power of 8) positions to find all solutions and my problem has much more positions (I counted (3^10)^10, maybe i make a mistake). I tried to run my code anyway, hoping to get at least one solution, but after running for about an hour, it crashed without giving a single solution.
My code is written in Javascript, I can provide it if needed.

What I need from you:

Even just one ready solution, without any code would be great. Ideally I'd like to get some advices how to build an algorithm.

Comment: Whilst I like this question, is this one for SO?